# Proving that any Lie algebra valued one-form on a principal bundle satisfying the appropriate conditions induces a horizontal subspace

Tags: lie-algebras, differential-forms, connections, principal-bundles

Let $\omega_p:T_pP\longrightarrow T_eG$ be any Lie-algebra valued one-form on a principal bundle $(P,\pi,M)$ satisfying
$$
(a)\;\;\omega_p(X^{A}_p)=A
$$
$$
(b)\;\;((\triangleleft g)^*\omega)_p(X_p)=(Ad_{g^{-1}})_*(\omega_p(X_p))
$$
where $X^{A}$ is the fundamental vector field induced by the Lie algebra element $A\in T_eG$.

I want to prove that any one-form satisfying these properties induces a horizontal subspace, ie, is in particular a *connection* one-form. Can anyone push me towards the right direction to start? I'm not even sure what I'm supposed to be driving at, what would a solution to this sort of thing look like?

Am I trying to prove that we are forced to define $\omega_p$ in such a way that it involves horizontal subspaces if we want it to satisfy the above properties, or is that barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I think Theorem 28.1 of Differential Geometry by Loring Tu and the next few sections should answer this.

Comment: I think that theorem and subsequent proof is for the converse of the theorem in question, namely theorem 28.1 in Tu asserts that a connection one-form satisfies properties (a) and (b). I want to prove that *any* Lie algebra valued one-form which satisfies (a) and (b) is necessarily a *connection* one-form.